# Archived App fails to open Text file, opens successfully from Xcode

Tags: c, xcode, file

I have a simple .txt file in my project that opens successfully from within Xcode.
When I archive the app the file fails to load crashing the app.
I have other 'assets' in the same folder as the text file that load no problem.

```
FILE *fp;
if (!(fp=fopen("highScores.txt", "r")))
{
    fprintf(stderr,"\nfailed to open file:%s\n","highScores.txt");
    exit(0);
}
```

In the .app product the text file is in the 'resources' folder together with other assets.

Thanks

Comment: "_crashing the app_" how is it possible while you test the _fopen_success and _exit_ if failed ? "_When I archive the app_ you mean making the _dmg _ then installing it to execute the result ? Are you sure _highScores.txt_ is packaged ? just look in the installation folder. Else that just means the current directory is not the one you suppose, print it at the execution to check

Comment: Ok, the app exits not crashes. Xcode does not create a dmg. When you archive and then export it, you get a nice .app with the icon and all. if you right click and explore the content of the .app folder the highscore.txt is indeed in the rescorces folder created by xcode. It also contains all the other assets, that do open.

Comment: do you open the other assets in the same way (_fopen_) ? are you sure you open them from the current .app rather from the initial location (rename the initial dir to be sure) ? Again when the open fails _print_ the current dir to know where it is

Comment: The other assets are .png and .wav files, they are opened by SDL. So no I dont use fopen to open them. As you can see I use a relative path for fopen. Whithin Xcode settings I designated the path to where everything sits, and eveything runs great from Xcode. The stand alone app does not open the text file. If i take out the text file loading part out and recreate the .app the app runs fine and all the assets are found just fine. Might be a difference between how SDL finds assets and how stdio finds assets

Comment: "_As you can see I use a relative path for fopen_" you do not use a path at all, you just try to open in the current working directory and it is not the one you suppose, you have to add a relative path to open in the right directory. But while you do not print it as I suggest you since the beginning you will not know where you are so you do not know what relative path to add ...

Comment: even if i move the text flie to the same folder where the executable sits, the problem persists. I thought that in the case of no path specified it will start looking in the current directory.

Comment: I put a way to know the path of the running executable, having it you can compute a relative path to a file under Resources or any other file installed with your application, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I execute an application under MacOS the working directory is / :-(

To be able to read files installed with the application one way is to read using a path relative to the path of the executable. To know the path of the running executable just use `getpid` and `proc_pidpath` :

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <libproc.h>
...
char path[PROC_PIDPATHINFO_MAXSIZE];

if (proc_pidpath(getpid(), path, sizeof(path)) > 0) {
  /* here path contains the path of the executable, for instance
     /Applications/.../xxx.app/Contents/MacOS/xxx */
}
```